# Javascript list passing to c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Asp.net MVC program in which i want to get a list from the View using Javascript and pass that list to the controller. I want to the variables in the list to be string type except for one to be int32. 
The problem is the list is either empty or does not pass. 
I tried to use stringify but it doesn't fill the requirments.

Here is the code from the javascript part:

```
$('#AddColumn').click(function () {

    var nodeURL = document.getElementById("IDHolder").innerHTML;
    var nodeConfig= nodeURL+".CONFIG";
    var nodeAdd=nodeURL+".CONFIG.AddColumn";
    var nodeName = $("#ColumnName").val();
    var nodeType = $("#ColumnType").data("kendoComboBox").value();
    var ListNodedet = [nodeName, nodeType];
    var Listmet = [nodeConfig, nodeAdd];
    var ListNodeDetails = JSON.stringify(ListNodedet);

    var ListMethod = JSON.stringify(Listmet);

    var select = 1;
    var url = "/Configuration/CallMethod";

    $.get(url, { ListNodeDetails:ListNodeDetails, ListMethod:ListMethod }, function (data) {
        $("#Data2").html(data);
    });
})
```

The C# code for the controller were it calls another method in models:

```
 public bool CallMethod(List<Variant> ListNodeDetails, List <string> ListMethod)
    {
var AddMethod = RxMUaClient.CallMethod(ListNodeDetails, ListMethod, "127.0.0.1:48030");
        return AddMethod;
    }
```

The Model:

```
public static bool CallMethod(List<Variant> ListNodeDetails, List<string> ListMethod, string iPAddress)
    {
        var serverInstance = GetServerInstance(iPAddress);
        if (serverInstance == null)
            return false;
        return serverInstance.CallMethod(ListNodeDetails, ListMethod);

    }
```

The service model

```
     public bool CallMethod(List<Variant> ListNodeDetails, List<string> ListMethod)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_mSession == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            NodeId objectID = NodeId.Parse(ListMethod[0]);
            NodeId Methodtype = NodeId.Parse(ListMethod[1]); ;
            List<Variant> inputArguments = ListNodeDetails;

            List<StatusCode> inputArgumentErrors = null;
            List<Variant> outputArguments = null;
            StatusCode error = _mSession.Call(
                objectID,
                Methodtype,
                inputArguments,
                new RequestSettings() { OperationTimeout = 10000 },
                out inputArgumentErrors,
                out outputArguments);
            if (StatusCode.IsBad(error))
            {
                Console.Write("Server returned an error while calling method: " + error.ToString());
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            return false;
        }

    }
```

At the end it calls some functions using OPC UA to add data.

Comment: Please, post your C# code!

Comment: Stringify the data passed to the `get()` call, rather than just the properties of it.

Comment: @Archer can you explain more what you are suggesting

Comment: I've modified your code to show what I meant, and posted it as an answer below.

Comment: @Archer thanks alot for your answer it helped me alot

Comment: No worries.  I deleted the answer because it turned out there were other issues (GET instead of POST, for example) that were also causing problems.  Your posted code after you fixed it is more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed it to be ajax function and it works well but only with one list form the lists passed to the method!
I dont know if this is because i read values from kendo box and text box, and they are different types but i tried to stringfy it and it still does not work. On the console both lists are out as strings. So still got a problem with passing the first List "ListNodeDetails"!

```
$('#AddColumn').click(function () {

    var nodeURL = document.getElementById("IDHolder").innerHTML;
    var nodeConfig= nodeURL+".CONFIG";
    var nodeAdd=nodeURL+".CONFIG.AddColumn";
    var nodeName = $("#ColumnName").val().toString();
    var nodeType = $("#ColumnType").data("kendoComboBox").value().toString();
    var ListNodedet = [nodeName, nodeType];
    var Listmet = [nodeConfig, nodeAdd];
    var params = {
        ListNodeDetails: ListNodedet,
        ListMethod: Listmet
    };


    var url = "/Configuration/CallMethod";

    console.log(params);  // added sanity check to make sure data is correctly passed

    var temp = {
        url: "/Configuration/CallMethod",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: function (params) {
            window.location.replace(params.redirect);
        }
    };
    $.ajax(temp);

})
```